# Kivy: Running the Kivy app with window minimized triggers an error on app closure. Why?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

Kivy 2.0 is giving out error only if I set the window to start off minimized.

Normally, `Kivy` closes gracefully with no traceback or error information on the console.
But recently, I added a functionality that starts up the kivy app with window minimized:
There are two ways to do it (either gives out an error when app is closed):

1. calling the `Window.minimize()` function
2. Setting kivy Config like this: `Config.set('graphics', 'window_state', 'minimized')`

No problem on window being minimized, but when I close the app using any of the above methods enabled, `Kivy` consoles out this error message:

```sh
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\main_app\main.py", line 501, in <module>        
     mainApp.run()
   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\main_app\.env\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 950, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\main_app\.env\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 584, in runTouchApp
     stopTouchApp()
   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\main_app\.env\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 625, in stopTouchApp
     EventLoop.close()
   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\main_app\.env\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 186, in close
     self.stop()
   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\main_app\.env\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 198, in stop
     provider.stop()
   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\main_app\.env\lib\site-packages\kivy\input\providers\wm_pen.py", line 114, in stop
     SetWindowLong_WndProc_wrapper(self.hwnd, self.old_windProc)
   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\main_app\.env\lib\site-packages\kivy\input\providers\wm_common.py", line 112, in _closure
     oldAddr = func(hWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, cast(wndProc, c_void_p).value)
 ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 3: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

What is going on here?

Here is the environment I am using:

*Python: `3.9.4 (tags/v3.9.4:1f2e308, Apr  4 2021, 13:14:17) [MSC v.1928 32 bit (Intel)] on win32`*

*Kivy: `2.0.0`*

Here is what you need to recreate the error:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'window_state', 'minimized')


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Hello World')

TestApp().run()
```

Run this app and close it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug.  Here is a workaround.  I noticed if the Window is allowed to open in its default size, and is then minimized.  There is no error.  This example minimizes the WIndow after it is opened.  You could add a second or 2 and display some info, like a splash screen - and then minimize the window.

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.clock import Clock


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Hello World')

    def on_start(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.win_min, 0)  # increase time to create a splash screen effect...

    def win_min(self, dt):
        Window.minimize()


TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It indeed looks like a bug and I opened a new issue on github. But I need to start off with window minimized and then close it at a later time. I appreciate your answer, but it did not help.

Comment: I am facing exactly the same problem and start off with window minimized as well. @Beki, did you find a workaround for this?

Comment: @BillBridge No there is no reply as of now. I just left it as it is - with the error message showing up on app closure.